# Mosquitto broker running with wrong conf file at boot

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I'm running a Mosquitto Broker on a Raspberry PI.

I placed a mosquitto.conf file on /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf with the content:

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

and another file in /etc/mosquitto/conf.g/mosquitto.conf with the content:

```
autosave_interval 1800

user mosquitto

connection_messages true
log_dest stderr
log_dest topic
log_type error
log_type warning
log_type notice
log_type information
log_type all
log_type debug
log_timestamp true

#message_size_limit 10240

password_file /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/osmc.pw
allow_anonymous false
#acl_file jp.acl

persistence true
persistence_file mosquitto.db
persistent_client_expiration 1m

#pid_file xxxx

retained_persistence true

#listener 1883
listener 1883

listener 8883
tls_version tlsv1.2
cafile /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/osmc.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/osmc.key
require_certificate false
```

When I run mosquitto with the command

```
$sudo mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf -d
```

The broker initializes correctly as I can see using:

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep mosquitto
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8883            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23266/mosquitto
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1883            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23266/mosquitto
tcp6       0      0 :::8883                 :::*                    LISTEN      23266/mosquitto
tcp6       0      0 :::1883                 :::*                    LISTEN      23266/mosquitto
```

But after a reboot, using the same command I notice that Mosquitto is not running on the port 8883

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep mosquitto
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1883            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      269/mosquitto
tcp6       0      0 :::1883                 :::*                    LISTEN      269/mosquitto
```

How can I run mosquitto with the right mosquitto.conf file on boot?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Raspbian Jessie. The docs say to place the config file in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/

However, my /etc/init.d/mosquitto file was looking for mosquitto.conf in the /etc/mosquitto folder. Read your file to see where it's looking on startup. Also check inside /etc/init/mosquitto.conf.

Either change the files in init.d and init or place your altered config file in etc/mosquitto to solve the problem.

Comment: Ok but inside my /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.d I set my config file with: include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d is that wrong?

Comment: I put all my configuration changes in the original conf file within etc/mosquitto. Did not use the include_dir. Have nothing in conf.d.

Just make sure etc/init.d/mosquitto and etc/init/mosquitto.conf point to the same location.

Then make sure there is 1) an actual conf file at that location and 2) it has the configuration commands you want inside it.